# How to exit grub rescue?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I want to delete the swap partition to free up space to increase the root partition, but accidentally when I restarted Ubuntu I got this:

[image]

I have made a live Ubuntu to solve this, but I can't close grub rescue. How to close grub rescue and solve this problem?

This is the output of GParted:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave from Grub's rescue mode and reboot the machine simply type

```
reboot
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Before doing that you should insert your live-USB or DVD. When the machine reboots, enter the BIOS/UEFI-settings to change the boot-order accordingly to boot from your live-USB or DVD.

It is hard to say what your problem really is, deleting the swap-partition usually doesn't result in a boot-failure, it will increase boot-time (at least this is my experience and may depend on the version of Ubuntu you use).

So you should add more information to your question. When booted into Ubuntu-live, open Nautilus (Files) and mount your Ubuntu-partition on your HDD/SSD with a left-click on it. You should see the file-system on your partition now. Browse to find the file /etc/fstab in this partition, open the file with a double-click, copy the content and paste it into your question.

Then open a terminal and run the command

```
lsblk -o +UUID
```

Copy the output and paste it into your question as well.

This will help us to determine what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, But how to solve the problem?

Comment: @GeorgeGhaleb Did you delete the swap-partition already?

Comment: Could you please take a look at GParted output? I think I deleted the whole `dev/sda2` [The GParted output image](https://imgur.com/a/9LNok) @mook765

Comment: @GeorgeGhaleb `/dev/sda2` is an `extended partition` and  can contain `logical partitions`. Looks like your deleted swap-partition was such a logical partition. `/dev/sda2` still exists but is empty. I think your installation is in `sda3` but I cant be sure. Try to follow the steps I added in my answer and report back.

Comment: @GeorgeGhaleb If you find out that you deleted your `/`-partition you can restore the partition with `testdisk` (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Gparted has also a data-rescue function which should be able to restore a deleted partition, but I never used this so far. I need a rest now and move to the bed. I will check out later how your progress is.

Comment: Does not work. Unknown command reboot

Comment: @mathtick This will not work in BusyBox but for sure in grub-rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- replace sdX and sdXn with your setup's partitions/drives:

  `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
  sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
  sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
  sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
  sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
  sudo chroot /mnt
  grub-install /dev/sdc
  grub-install --recheck /dev/sdc
  update-grub`

Answer (score -1):

First you have to boot using Windows 7/8/10 DVD or bootable windows usb. Then, choose “Repair Computer ” -> “Troubleshoot” -> “Advanced Options” -> “Command Prompt”

In Command prompt type as follows

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

> bootrec.exe /fixboot

> exit.

Restart your system.

It will boot into windows 10 automatically as the GRUB loader will be overwrite by Win loader.

Go to Disk management and delete the Ubuntu partitions to remove Ubuntu completely. MAke new partition of deleted partitions.