"Next" button grayed out after creating partition table for Ubuntu
I am trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my laptop, using the .iso disk image burned on a USB. Since I already had a partition with both Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 installed, I tried to manually change it. My original partition, probably very badly done, was:

After deleting that part of the table, where my previous Ubuntu version was, this is my new table:

However, the "Next" button is grayed out and I don't see how to proceed. I found a similar question here where the issue was that the user hadn't specified "/" for any partition, but that is not my case, I believe. Any ideas? Thank you!
Edit: this is the rest of my partition table:


Scroll down a bit and check the nvme0n1 device for any inconsistencies with what you show.

Have you got an UEFI partition with the right flags set?

@ubfan1 What could be an inconsistency? I suppose that if I tried to allocate more space than available, it wouldn't let me, right? I edited my post to add an image of the rest of my partition table.

@david What do you mean by the right flags? I'm very new to this, but I had installed Ubuntu before doing the partitions myself and never had this issue. I edited my post to add the rest of the partition table. I only modified the space where the previous Ubuntu installation was located, so I really don't get what I could have done wrong...

The UEFI partition needs the 'boot' and 'esp' flag set. The 'swap' partition needs the 'swap' flag set. It is not showing the flags in your picture but that might be normal. If you have got another OS in the rig it will be using the UEFI partition to boot from. If so I wouldl advice leaving it alone.

I solved it! The solution was to start by defining a partition with type VFAT and mounted as /boot. It automatically leads to the creation of a smaller partition that appears as /boot/efi, and then I could create the /swap and / partitions with no issues. Once that was done, the "Next" button got activated!


A /boot-partition should never be VFAT but ext4. A /boot-patition is not needed at all. The one you created is quite small and you will get soon out of space due to kernel upgrades. The culprit was that your /boot/efi-partition was VFAT and it needs to be a valid FAT partition, such as FAT32, FAT16.

@mook765 Maybe my installation failed because of that. I got an error, rebooted, and now I'm stuck in GNU Grub and don't know how to get out or boot again from my USB to retry :(

You should be able to reboot the install media from the BIO boot menu.

https://askubuntu.com/a/980218/590937

@mook765 Thank you, I managed to boot from my USB by using these instructions: https://szymonkrajewski.pl/how-to-boot-system-from-usb-using-grub/

@mook765 However, I'm unsure of how I should set up the partition table to avoid the installation failing again. Would a swap partition and a / partition be enough? Don't I also need to add /boot for the dual boot menu to find Ubuntu later?

You only need / (Ext4) and /boot/efi (Fat32) , a swap partition is not needed, nowadays swapfile is used. Also 32 GB swap is huge and mostly wasted unless you have special requirements. A /home (Ext4) partition makes sense. SIzes: boot/efi 300MB, / 60GB, /home (rest of dikspace).

@mook765 Thank you! Sadly, after installlation, I was redirected to Grub again and I see no way to make the usual dual-boot menu apear...

We cannot diskuss this in the comment section. Please open a new question with more details such as hardware specs and a link to your boot info summary.
